# Listening capacity of port

Tags: tcp, port

I have client server chat application. where i am using TCP ports.

My client want me to modify the application so that it can handle millions of login and chat request.

There are separate ports for listening Login request, Listening messages and listening update messages.

Suppose I am listening port 5000 for listening to login request from client. now the big question is : Is that single port is able to listen to the millions of login request simultaneously.

Thanks

please reply as soon as possible its very critical part of my project.

Comment: This sounds like your client threw a totally arbitrary requirement at you. Millions of simultaneous login and chat requests? Seriously?

Comment: ya may be ..but i have to do it..right>

Comment: Not really. You *could* tell them that it's a crazy requirement, and that you can't do it. That's what I would tell them if it were my client - setting up a server environment that can deal with millions of simultaneous requests is a job for an experienced systems administrator, maybe even more than one. There are zillions of factors to be taken into consideration - servers. Server farm connectivity. Application load. Clustering. The purpose of the application. The list goes on and on and on

Comment: well i like to work on challenges. i am year old developer by d way.
I want that list you talking about in previous post..
what is it.list it out all for me  please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer to Is server capable of listening to millions of tcp request? Ans is: Yes In linux system u can increase File descriptor value to maximum no . and that linux server will listen to million request simulteneously

Answer (score 0):

Ports are only a way of accessing a particular server app.

The question is whether your host is capable of dealing with the number of requests your customer anticipates. As you are undoubtedly aware web servers generally listen on TCP port 80 but they could just as easily listen on port 5000, response time is always to do with host capabilities, there is nothing special about particular ports.